# shared library loading

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

My app shows that that dynamic linking is ok.

```
[root@centos udpfltr_fork]# ldd udpfltr
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00dbe000)
    libnfnetlink.so.0 => /usr/lib/libnfnetlink.so.0 (0x005de000)
    libnetfilter_queue.so.1 => /usr/lib/libnetfilter_queue.so.1 (0x004a5000)
    libnglogc.so.0 => /usr/lib/libnglogc.so.0 (0x00a51000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x001b9000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x0019a000)
```

but when its invoked it stops with following error:

```
./udpfltr: error while loading shared libraries: libnglogc.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm clueless about what's actually happening. I've tried with setting $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, reloading ldcache by ldconfig etc.

Comment: Did you verify the file actually exists by doing an `ls -la /usr/lib/libnglogc.so.0` as it is possible the file existed at one point but does not anymore.

Comment: Also use `objdump -x` and possibly `file` and `ldd` on `/usr/lib/libnglogc.so.0` etc to check it.

Comment: in my case on an Ubuntu the package `lsb-core` (or some of the dependency packges) was missing.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the reason:-
1)check $LD_LIBRARY_PATH - this path may not have location where libglogc.so.0 resides
  unset $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and then set this to .so location